# Sql Server string interning

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, compression

We have a table where we store all the exceptions (message, stackTrace, etc..), the table is getting big and we would like to reduce it.

There are plenty of repeated StackTraces, Messages, etc, but enabling compression produces a modest size reduction (10%) while I think much bigger benefits could come if somehow Sql Server will [intern the strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) in some per-column hash-table.

I could get some of the benefits if I normalize the table and extract StackTraces to another one, but exception messages, exception types, etc.. are also repeated.

Is there a way to enable string interning for some column in Sql Server?

Comment: I don't see any conceptual difference between normalizing the data and  string interning (using references to repeated values rather than repeating the values) except that one is automatic and the other is manual. And I bet if you tested what @Aaron recommended you see very large size differences.

Comment: Size change will depend on the selectivity you have for Message / Type etc.

Comment: There's no conceptual difference, but there are plenty of practical ones: 
* The schema & queries change
* What used to be a simple Insert will became N queries, and potentially N inserts. 

I think repeated strings are common enough that having a built-in functionality could be useful.

Comment: I wouldn't call a join "plenty of queries." if query complexity is a major roadblock, you can always create a view, or push the data to a data warehouse and denormalize there. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in way to do this. You could easily do something like:

```
SELECT MessageID = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1), Message 
  INTO dbo.Messages 
  FROM dbo.HugeTable GROUP BY Message;

ALTER TABLE dbo.HugeTable ADD MessageID INT;

UPDATE h
   SET h.MessageID = m.MessageID
   FROM dbo.HugeTable AS h
   INNER JOIN dbo.Messages AS m
   ON h.Message = m.Message;

ALTER TABLE dbo.HugeTable DROP COLUMN Message;
```

Now you'll need to do a few things:

- Change your logging procedure to perform an upsert to the Messages table
- Add proper indexes to the messages table (wasn't sure of Message data type) and PK
- Add FK to MessageID column
- Rebuild indexes on HugeTable to reclaim space
- Do this in a test environment first!

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron, I was expecting something like this. 
I will definitely do so for stack traces, but I think exception type names are too small for having their own table & exception messages have more variations. If there where a build-in solution however I will use it on all three. Don't you?

Comment: Depends on the size of message column, average value size, and how many unique values I guess. No golden rule without more details.

Comment: I understand. What I mean is that, in my opinion, there are times where creating a look-up message table looks like too much trouble, but I will set a Intern=true flag on the column.

Comment: If that were a feature, sure. But while that would save you space perhaps, it's much like compression - storing and retrieving the values will cost you in CPU. So in addition to the other details it's also a trade-off consideration whether your current system is CPU- or I/O-bound, and how far off your move is to faster I/O because the performance profile will change.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron's posting answers the questions of adding interning to a table, but afterwards you will need to modify your application code and stored-procedures to work with the new schema.

...or so you might think. You can actually create a `VIEW` that returns data matching the old schema, and you can also support `INSERT` operations on the view too, which are translated into child operations on the `Messages` and `HugeTable` tables. For readability I'll use the names `InternedStrings` and `ExceptionLogs` for the tables.

So if the old table was this:

```
CREATE TABLE ExceptionLogs (
    LogId         int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Message       nvarchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    ExceptionType nvarchar(512)  NOT NULL,
    StackTrace    nvarchar(4096) NOT NULL
)
```

And the new tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE InternedStrings (
    StringId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Value    nvarchar(max)     NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE ExceptionLogs2 ( -- note the new name
    LogId         int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Message       int NOT NULL,
    ExceptionType int NOT NULL,
    StackTrace    int NOT NULL
)
```

Add an index to `InternedStrings` to make the value lookups faster:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_U_InternedStrings_Value ON InternedStrings ( Value ASC )
```

Then you would also have a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW ExeptionLogs AS

    SELECT
        LogId,
        MessageStrings      .Value AS Message,
        ExceptionTypeStrings.Value AS ExceptionType,
        StackTraceStrings   .Value AS StackTrace
    FROM
        ExceptionLogs2

        INNER JOIN InternedStrings AS MessageStrings       ON
            MessageStrings.StringId = ExceptionLogs2.Message

        INNER JOIN InternedStrings AS ExceptionTypeStrings ON
            ExceptionTypeStrings.StringId = ExceptionLogs2.ExceptionType

        INNER JOIN InternedStrings AS StackTraceStrings    ON
            StackTraceStrings.StringId = ExceptionLogs2.StackTrace
```

And to handle `INSERT` operations from unmodified clients:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ExceptionLogsInsertHandler
    ON ExceptionLogs INSTEAD OF INSERT AS

    DECLARE @messageId int = SELECT StringId FROM InternedStrings WHERE Value = inserted.Message
    IF @messageId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO InternedStrings ( Text ) VALUES ( inserted.Message )
        SET @messageId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    DECLARE @exceptionTypeId int = SELECT StringId FROM InternedStrings WHERE Value = inserted.ExceptionType
    IF @exceptionTypeId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO InternedStrings ( Text ) VALUES ( inserted.ExceptionType )
        SET @exceptionTypeId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    DECLARE @stackTraceId int = SELECT StringId FROM InternedStrings WHERE Value = inserted.StackTrace
    IF @stackTraceId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO InternedStrings ( Text ) VALUES ( inserted.StackTrace )
        SET @stackTraceId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    INSERT INTO ExceptionLogs2 ( Message, ExceptionType, StackTrace )
    VALUES ( @messageId, @exceptionTypeId, @stackTraceId )
```

Note this `TRIGGER` can be improved: it only supports single-row insertions, and is not entirely concurrency-safe, though because previous data won't be mutated it means that there's a slight risk of data *duplication* in the `InternedStrings` table - and because of a `UNIQUE` index the insert will fail. There are different possible ways to handle this, such as using a `TRANSACTION` and changing the queries to use `holdlock` and `updlock`.